# How to read a xml file and change some values in child node then write as another or same using VBA?

Tags: xml, vba

I have a file which is in xml. But I need to edit some values and save it as new or same file.

for eg : need to edit "speed" value from 100 to 200 and save.

furthermore, I want to loop through all "Pathnode" child to reach "variable" which is my interest. Number of "Pathnode" may vary in between "Inputs" and "Variable"

```
<AnalysisCase Name="case 1\Load cycle"/>
<Inputs>    
 <PathNode Name="New Design">
  <PathNode Name="Input">
    <PathNode Name="## Property ##">
      <PathNode Name="Component Load Case">
        <Variable Name="Speed" Value="100" />
        <Variable Name="Torque" Value="150"/>
      </PathNode>
    </PathNode>
   </PathNode>
 </PathNode>
</Inputs>
```

Comment: why do you want to loop through all rather than match with xpath and then set value? Can there be only one Speed or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read into an HTMLDocument parser using HTMLObject library then use querySelector and SetAttribute

```
HTML.querySelector("[Name=Speed]").SetAttribute "Value", "200"
```

Same principle if you use xml parser and read into xml document variable. See second code example.

Note that your xml must be well formed which the above is not. I treat your first element as the root which should be well formed.

I assume first match is required. If more than one match then use

`querySelectorAll` with `HTMLDocument` and loop from i = 0 to matches.Length -1

Use

`xmlDoc.SelectNodes` with `DOMDocument` and `For Each` over each match in matches

---

**HTMLDocument:**

To read local xml into HTMLDocument variable you can use FileSystemObject

```
Public Function GetHTMLFileContent(ByVal filePath As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim fso As Object, hFile As Object, hString As String, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set hFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath)

    Do Until hFile.AtEndOfStream
        hString = hFile.ReadAll()
    Loop
    html.body.innerHTML = hString
    Set GetHTMLFileContent = html

End Function
```

---

**XML DOMDocument:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, node As Object ' IXMLDOMElement  ''<early  bound requires reference to Microsoft XML v3 or v6 depending on your Excel version
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 'New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False
        If Not .Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Set node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Variable[@Name='Speed' and @Value]")
    If Not node Is Nothing Then
         node.setAttribute "Value", "200"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Testing xml**

```
<AnalysisCase Name="case 1\Load cycle">
    <Inputs>
        <PathNode Name="New Design">
            <PathNode Name="Input">
                <PathNode Name="## Property ##">
                    <PathNode Name="Component Load Case">
                        <Variable Name="Speed" Value="100" />
                        <Variable Name="Torque" Value="150" />
                    </PathNode>
                </PathNode>
            </PathNode>
        </PathNode>
    </Inputs>
</AnalysisCase>
```

---

References:

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Thanks for reply , but I am getting error on "IXMLDOMElement" that userdefined type not defined

Comment: Change to Dim node As Object or add reference in vbe> tools > references > add reference to MS XML v (where v is what ever version for your system.)  I have updated answer. If you want to use faster early binding then use the commented out versions in script - but those require the XML reference.

Comment: Hi Again thanks for update, But my file is not getting modified. as per this code speed value should be 200 right , after execution. But it still same :(
Do I have to create separate xml ?

Comment: It should modify the DOMDocument or HTMLDocument variable. You would need to save that or overwrite file.

Comment: Thanks it worked !! I did modify a bit from some other sources and added 
xmlDoc.save ("path") to save file

Comment: -Done, I have small doubt, incase you have time, please go through below.
I want to loop through all \\variable. but how do I do that?

Comment: For Each node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Variable")

Comment: okay. But it is calling all \\variable in my xml. Suppose I want to check only under <input> ,what should I do ? 
I promise this is my last question :)

Note : number of /pathnodes in between /variable and /input varies

Comment: Add /Inputs parent to xpath For Each node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Inputs/Variable")

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is how to read and write text files (since that's what xml files are) in vba.

I recommend reading [this article](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-text-files) on the subject that should give you all the information you need to get started.